# Find existing bookmark folder by title?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to bring back the **folder id** of any bookmark folder which has a **title** matching a given string.

Problem is it doesn't return back folder ids when the text is the same :C

This is my code:

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarks) 
{
  search_for_url(bookmarks, "herpaderp");
});
```

```
function search_for_title(bookmarks, title)
{
  for(i=0; i < bookmarks.length; i++)
  { 
    if(bookmarks[i].url != null && bookmarks[i].title == title)
    {
      // Totally found a folder that matches!
      return bookmarks[i].id;
    }
    else
    {
      if(bookmarks[i].children)
      {  
        // inception recursive stuff to get into the next layer of children
        return search_for_title(bookmarks[i].children, title);
      }
    }
  }

  // No results :C
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your `search_for_title` function.

1. The variable `i` **must** be local. To make it a local variable, you have to use **var** i = 0 instead of `i = 0` in the `for` statement.
2. `search_for_title` returns `false` when it can't find a bookmark that has the specified title, but you still need to look into the next item, so after recursively calling `search_for_title`, you `return` the return value *only* if the bookmark has been found. Otherwise, search should be continued instead of returning `false`.

Here's the code I tested to run correctly:

```
function search_for_title(bookmarks, title)
{
  for(var i=0; i < bookmarks.length; i++)
  { 
    if(bookmarks[i].url != null && bookmarks[i].title == title)
    {
      // Totally found a folder that matches!
      return bookmarks[i].id;
    }
    else
    {
      if(bookmarks[i].children)
      {  
        // inception recursive stuff to get into the next layer of children
        var id = search_for_title(bookmarks[i].children, title);
        if(id)
        {
          return id;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // No results :C
  return false;
}
```